# Array of structures with parfor in Matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab, structure, parfor

I am using Matlab to work on my project, and I want to use "parfor" as a part of my code that returns an array of structures in each its iteration,  But when I run my code I got some errors. I just tried to bring an example of my problem in the simplest way. Will be appreciated any helps! Here is the example:

```
clear;
clc;
% An arbitrary number 
constant_Number=3;
tic
parfor i=1:2
    k=[constant_Number,i];
    r(i)=test(k);
end
toc
```

and test function is as follows:

```
function [a]=test(k)
   a.first=k(1) * k(2);
   a.second=k(1)+k(2);
   b.first=k(1)/k(2);
   b.second=k(1);
   a=[a;b];
end
```

One note is that when I just return one structure, it works fine but when I have more than one (adding b for instance), I got the following error: "Unable to perform assignment because the indices on the left side are not compatible with the size of the right side."

Thanks,
Ali

Comment: You need to preallocate `r`. Then assign `r(:,i) = test(k)`.

Comment: Thanks for your message but it does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find the solution, just need to define a cell array and then finally merge them! Follow can be an answer:

```
clear;
clc;
% An arbitrary number 
constant_Number=3;
% Define an arbitrary array of structure 
arb_arr=[];
% Define an arbitrary cell array
r={};
tic
parfor i=1:2
    k=[constant_Number,i];
    r{i}=test(k);
end



for i=1:2
   arb_arr=[arb_arr;r{i}];
end


toc
```

Comment: With this solution you should also preallocate `r`: `r = cell(2,1)` (or whatever size corresponds). Then concatenate with `arb_arr=[r{:}];` (no loop necessary).

Comment: Pre-allocation is always a good idea, but in fact for `parfor` it usually doesn't matter because the `parfor` analysis is always able to deduce the required sizes.

Comment: Thanks, @CrisLuengo for your recommendations!

Comment: Thanks, @Edric for your recommendations!